# Update nested entry in array list with anchor parent

Tags: yq

Given a yaml file:

```
Organizations:
  - &org-o1
    O_Endpoints:
      - o1.address:1234
  - &org-p1
    Anchors:
      - Host: p1.address
  - &org-o2
    O_Endpoints:
      - o2.address:2345
```

I want to update the port value in `Organizations.[&org-o1].O_Endpoints`.

I could use this command to make the change:

```
yq eval -i '.Organizations.[0].O_Endpoints = "o1.address:5555" $file
```

But I can't always predict the position [x] of `org-o1`, so this command is not sufficient.

I could also use this command to update the `O_Endpoints` value for all array entries:

```
yq eval -i '.Organizations.[].O_Endpoints[0] = "o1.address:5555"' $File
```

However, this command adds `O_Endpoints` to those entries which do not currently have them.  I only want to update existing entries, not add new ones.

If org-o1 was not an anchor, I could use the following command to update it without knowing its exact position:

```
L=$(yq eval '.Organizations.[] | select(. == "org-o1") | path | .[-1]' $File) #get Line Number
L=$L yq eval -i '.Organizations[env(L)].O_Endpoints = "o1.address:5555"' $File
```

Can I do something similar with an entry whose path includes an anchor in an array?

Comment: I don't think yq supports searching by anchors. You can always explode, but its tough to reconstruct back

Comment: Take a look at [Update an object field defined in an anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212928/update-an-object-field-defined-in-an-anchor/68214318#68214318). It turns out that `yq` has a bug with updating anchors. I think the bug also affects what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can search nodes by their anchor name like so:

```
yq '(.Organizations[] | select(anchor=="org-o1") |.O_Endpoints[0]) = "o1.address:5555"' file.yaml
```

Disclaimer: I wrote yq