# Update an object field defined in an anchor

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml file which looks like this:

```yaml
item_value: &item_value
  value: true

array:
  - name: item_1
    <<: *item_value
  - name: item_2
    <<: *item_value
```

I would like to update the value of the first item in order to have something like this:

```yaml
array:
  - name: item_1
    value: false
  - name: item_2
    value: true
```

The only way I found to have something similar is with this expression that I found [in the yq (v4) documentation](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-arrays-of-objects-together-matching-on-a-key):

```sh
yq e '( explode(.) | .array.[] | select(.name == "item_1") | .value = false ) as $test | explode(.) | .array.[] |= (. as $cur | $cur * ($test | select(.name == $cur.name)))' test.yaml
```

This seems really tricky and I noticed that with the following shorter expression I have the same (bad) result (and I don't understand why this one works by the way):

```sh
yq e '( explode(.) | .array.[] | select(.name == "item_1") | .value = false ) as $test' test.yaml
```

And the result:

```yaml
item_value:
  value: false
array:
  - name: item_1
    value: false
  - name: item_2
    value: false
```

Comment: looks to be a bug. You should raise it in https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use merge to break persistant links to the alias :

```sh
yq e '(.array[] | select(.name=="item_1")) |= explode(.) * {"value": false}' test.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) (the Python version, not the Go version you are using)
I can solve your task.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE='
item_value: &item_value
  value: true

array:
  - name: item_1
    <<: *item_value
  - name: item_2
    <<: *item_value
'

yq -y --arg name "item_1" '(.array[] | select(.name == $name) | .value) |= false' <<< "$FILE"
```

### output

```yaml
item_value:
  value: true
array:
  - value: false
    name: item_1
  - value: true
    name: item_2
```

---

Using [yq](https://mikefarah.github.io/yq/) (the Go version you are using) I also get faulty output with the same expression.

`yq e '(.array[] | select(.name == "item_1") | .value) |= false' test.yaml`

### output

```yaml
item_value: &item_value
  value: false
array:
  - name: item_1
    !!merge <<: *item_value
  - name: item_2
    !!merge <<: *item_value
```

using as input

```json
array:
  - name: item_1
    value: true
  - name: item_2
    value: true
```

everything works fine:

`yq e '(.array[] | select(.name == "item_1") | .value) |= false' test.yaml`

```json
array:
  - name: item_1
    value: false
  - name: item_2
    value: true
```

So it is a bug in this `yq` implementation.

Comment: Thanks @jpseng, I can't use Python version but it shows that there's a bug in the Go version.
The reason why I use explode command was to avoid the values to be updated in each item as in your 2nd output. I'm really surprised by the behavior of your first Python execution...

Comment: You don't need the `explode` filter. I checked it with the `yq` implementation in Go using an input file without anchors and added it to the answer.

Comment: If you cannot use `yq` (Python), another workaround would be to use `jq`: Convert yaml to json, process it with `jq` and convert it back to yaml. But all the anchors get lost this way.

`yq e -j test.yaml | jq '(.array[] | select(.name == "item_1") | .value) |= false' | yq e -P -`